# C++ input function that calls itself

Tags: c++, string, input

I have a question regarding a function that takes a string(command, first, and last name) and executes depending on what that input is. My function has several else if statement, and if the input is considered invalid, how do I let the user type in another command? Thank you

```
EXAMPLE_INPUT = "CREATE John Doe"

std::string get_input(std::string& s)
{ 
  std::string raw_input;
  std::getline(std::cin, raw_input);
  std::istringstream input(raw_input);

  std::string command;
  std::string first_name;
  std::string last_name;

  input >> command;
  input >> first_name;
  input >> last_name;

  //what do I return? I can't return all 3 (command, first, last)
}

void std::string input_function(std::string& s)
{
  if (s == "ONE")
  {
    call function_one()   
  }

  else if (s == "TWO")
  {
    call function_two()
  } 

  else
  {
    //How do I get user to type in something else(call get_input() again)?
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to return a `std::string` since you just parsed it and split it into three different strings... Maybe you want a struct.

Comment: A struct is probably your best bet for the first, and perhaps returning a `bool` indicating command execution success would be appropriate for the second.

Comment: so a struct with those 3 elements, each being a string. So when my second function takes in a string, I give it struct.element?

Comment: @Steven If you are only interested in the command portion, you would pass only the command stored in the struct.  However, you could just as easily pass the whole struct and read only the command portion, especially if the name factors into the execution of functions called by the second function.

Comment: Stupid question, but I forgot if a struct will die if I initialize it inside a function. I'm assuming the struct will die after the function ends. Is this correct? I would assume that I need to dynamically allocate the struct. Just making sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return more than one variable, consider enclosing them in a struct or a class and return that. About typing in another command, you theoretically could use recursion as your post suggest but that's just wrong, it will crash the program if the user types wrong words in too many times. Instead you could use a simple while loop:

```
bool success = false;
while(!success){
    /* check the input, if it's correct - process it and set success to true */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 struct input_result {
   std::string command;
   std::string first_name;
   std::string last_name;
 };
```

have your get input function return the above (an `input_result`).

The function that processes the input should have a means of returning failure or an error.  Then the code that calls `get_input` can call the processing code, notice it failed, and loop back to calling `get_input`.

You can wrap the two up into one function called `get_and_process` that first gets, then processes, and if the processing fails repeats the get.

You should only take things by bare `&` if you plan on changing them -- if not, take by `const &` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You *usually* want to do this by putting the related data together into a `struct` (or `class`):

```
struct whatever {
    std::string command;
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
};
```

...then overloading `operator>>` for that type:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, whatever &w) { 
    return is >> w.command >> w.first_name >> w.last_name;
}
```

This allows *all* the data to be "returned" in a single structure, *and* the status of the input operation to be returned in the `istream` that's actually returned, so you can read an item, and check whether that succeeded in a single operation:

```
std::ifstream in("myfile.txt");
whatever x;

if ( in >> x)
    // input succeeded, show some of the data we read:
    std::cout << "command: " << x.command 
              << "\tName: " << x.last_name << ", " << x.first_name << "\n";
else
    std::cerr << "Input failed";
```

To give the user another chance to enter data when reading fails, you'd typically do something like this:

```
while (!in >> x)
    "Please Enter command, First name and last name:\n";
```

Note that when reading data (especially data you expect to be entered interactively by the user) you almost always want to check the input this way.